# The model User could not be resolved from the registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

So, I was following the guide from bookshelf to create a simple one to one relationship using books and summary [example](https://bookshelfjs.org/tutorial-one-to-one.html).
So, I created the book model as below:

```
const dbConfig = require('../data/db');
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(dbConfig)

const Book = bookshelf.model('Book', {
    tableName: 'books',
    summary() {
      return this.hasOne('Summary')
    }
  })

  module.exports = Book
```

and I created the summary model as per below:

```
const dbConfig = require('../data/db');
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(dbConfig)
const Summary = bookshelf.model('Summary', {
    tableName: 'summaries',
    book() {
      return this.belongsTo('Book')
    }
  })

  
  module.exports = Summary
```

for testing I created a few seeds to insert some items into the database. so I can do some testing with this.

```
exports.seed = async function(knex) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  await knex('books').del()
  await knex('books').insert([
    {id: 1, name: 'A series of unfortunate events'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Sherlock Holmes'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Harry potter'}
  ]);

  await knex('summaries').del()
  await knex('summaries').insert([{ id:1,details:'This is a really funny book. you gotta read this by lemony snicket',book_id:1
  },
  { id:2,details:'This is a really witty and intelligent book of holmes. He is an amazing detective after all. written by sir arthur conan doyale',book_id:2
  },
  { id:3,details:'This is a written by jk rowling',book_id:3
  }


])


};
```

I'm using express routes to go to specific page. it returns everything when I do fetchAll without any complex queries. but when I try to fetch only a specific summary id from books it doesn't seem to be working.

in v1/routes/summaryRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const Summary  = require('../../model/summary')


router.get('/',async(req,res)=>{

    let books = await new  Summary({id:1}).fetch({withRelated: ['books']})
    .then(function(){

        res.json(books.toJSON());

    })
    .catch(Summary.NotFoundError,function(err){

        res.send('empty response. :/');
        console.log('caught unhandled exception.. so happy :) ')
        console.log(err)


    });
    

})


module.exports = router
```

I keep getting the below error code:

> Error: books is not defined on the model.
> at EagerRelation. (C:\Users\bitcot\work\nodejs\node_modules\bookshelf\lib\base\eager.js:50:15)
> at EagerRelation.tryCatcher (C:\Users\bitcot\work\nodejs\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
> at EagerRelation.fetch (C:\Users\bitcot\work\nodejs\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:15:34)
> at Child._handleEager (C:\Users\bitcot\work\nodejs\node_modules\bookshelf\lib\model.js:1526:56)

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like a simple typo. It is basically telling you that you do not have a relation called `books` on your `Summary` model when you try to fetch it via `withRelated`.

You have defined the relation on your `Summary` model as `book`

```js
const Summary = bookshelf.model('Summary', {
    tableName: 'summaries',
    book() {
        return this.belongsTo('Book')
    }
})
```

However when you are trying to fetch this relation you are calling it `books` (with as `s`)

```
{withRelated: ['books']}
```

Since it looks to be a one-to-many relationship I would say the singular version is correct, so you just need to change your `withRelated` to `book` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks. but the issue was that I was declaring the above statement twice. 

const dbConfig = require('../data/db');
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(dbConfig)

The above statement should have been called only once in javascript and that was the issue.